# Is proxmox "portable"?

Tags: proxmox

Ubuntu seems to be portable: an Ubuntu SSD can be move from one PC to another, so long as the PC is older than the Ubuntu release year.

I understand that ProxMox is also a Debian distro.   Ubuntu 17.x. would not install on  2020 x64 hardware.  I would like to outfit an SSD that will run 17.x on my office's (Dell Optiplex Micro 3090) and my home's Optiplex 7010 DT (2012 X64)

Assume that ProxMox SSD will run 17.x in a VM and is installed on the 2020 hardware (Dell Optiplex Micro 3090).   Will the ssd be "portable": the SSD runs in in a 2014 X64 platform (Dell Optiplex 7010)?

Comment: Can't see why not. Why don't you try it?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas.  Always good to hear from you.   If it is NOT possible, then I was hoping that someone would save me time and I could avoid finding out the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about what you are trying to achieve here.

> so long as the PC is older than the Ubuntu release year.

Nope. That's not a contraint. It *is* possible that an old distro will not have the drivers required for newer hardware. (I presume you know that Ubuntu 17 is way past its EOL and should be considered insecure).

> Assume that ProxMox SSD will run 17.x in a VM

Wait. You want to transfer all of Proxmox as well as the Ubuntu 17 VM? Why? Yes, it should work, but wouldn't it be simpler to run Proxmox at both ends and just move the VM?

In the latter case, In addition to the VM you are interested in, you would need to create a ghost VM at the other end. Both would need to use Directory storage (rather than LVM-thin) and to move...

- shutdown the VM
- umount the disk which you previously mounted at the Proxmox directory storage location
- move drive to other node
- mount drive on directory storage
- start VM

However its not really a common use-case. It would be much safer to replicate the changes across 2 VMs.